# If $X_n\overset{P}\nrightarrow 0$ and $X_na_n \overset{P}\to 0$, do we have $a_n\to0$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $X_n\overset{P}\nrightarrow 0$ and $X_na_n \overset{P}\to 0$, do we have $a_n\to0$? It seems trivial, but I'm not sure how to write this down correctly using the definition of convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X_n=X$ for  $n$ even and $0$ for  $n$ odd. Let $a_n=0$ for  $n$ even and $1$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

Set $X_n = 1 - (-1)^n$ and $a_n = 1 + (-1)^n.$

Then $X_n, a_n$ don't converge but $X_na_n = 0$ obviously converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrianMoehring & @KaboMurphy (by similar counter example) showed it isn't true in general case.

But for conditions that it holds:

**1)** Sequence $X_n \mapsto X \not= 0$.

**2)** Sequence $|X_n| > \epsilon > 0$.

**3)** Sequence $X_n$ be monotonic sequence.

You may find some more yourself.

Comment: Thanks! How to prove it for example the second condition?

Comment: First notice: $X_n a_n \longmapsto 0 \Longrightarrow |X_n a_n| \longmapsto 0$. Also by second condition $|X_n a_n| > \epsilon |a_n| \geqslant 0 \Longrightarrow \epsilon |a_n| \longmapsto 0 \Longrightarrow |a_n| \longmapsto 0 \Longrightarrow a_n \longmapsto 0$.